# Dynamically query Parent object with jpa querydsl

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I have the following code to dynamically generate a Predicate:

```
static BooleanExpression getPredicate(SearchCriteria criteria) {
    try {
        Field field = QDeployment.class.getDeclaredField(criteria.getKey());
        String criteriaValue = criteria.getValue();
        Path<?> val = (Path<?>) field.get(new QDeployment("deployment"));

        if (val != null) {
            if (criteria.getOperator().equals(Operator.EQUALS)) {
                if (val instanceof NumberPath) {
                    return ((NumberPath) val).eq(criteriaValue);
                } else if (val instanceof QArmsExpedition) {
                    return ((QArmsExpedition) val).expeditionId.eq(Integer.valueOf(criteriaValue));
                } else if (val instanceof StringPath) {
                    return ((StringPath) val).eq(criteriaValue);
                } else {
                    throw new FimsRuntimeException("Invalid Query Operator for column.", 400);
                }
            } else if (criteria.getOperator().equals(Operator.CONTAINS)) {
                if (val instanceof StringPath) {
                    return ((StringPath) val).contains(criteriaValue);
                } else {
                    throw new FimsRuntimeException("Invalid Query Operator for column.", 400);
                }
            } else if (criteria.getOperator().equals(Operator.ENDS_WITH)) {
                if (val instanceof StringPath) {
                    return ((StringPath) val).endsWith(criteriaValue);
                } else {
                    throw new FimsRuntimeException("Invalid Query Operator for column.", 400);
                }
            } else if (criteria.getOperator().equals(Operator.STARTS_WITH)) {
                if (val instanceof StringPath) {
                    return ((StringPath) val).startsWith(criteriaValue);
                } else {
                    throw new FimsRuntimeException("Invalid Query Operator for column.", 400);
                }
            } else if (criteria.getOperator().equals(Operator.GREATER_THEN)) {
                if (val instanceof NumberPath) {
                    return ((NumberPath) val).gt(Float.parseFloat(criteriaValue));
                } else if (val instanceof StringPath) {
                    return ((StringPath) val).gt(criteriaValue);
                }
            } else if (criteria.getOperator().equals(Operator.LESS_THEN)) {
                if (val instanceof NumberPath) {
                    return ((NumberPath) val).lt(Float.parseFloat(criteriaValue));
                } else if (val instanceof StringPath) {
                    return ((StringPath) val).lt(criteriaValue);
                }
            } else if (criteria.getOperator().equals(Operator.IN)) {
                // split string removing any whitespace
                if (val instanceof StringPath) {
                    return ((StringPath) val).in(criteriaValue.trim().split("\\s,\\s|,\\s|,"));
                } else {
                    throw new FimsRuntimeException("Invalid Query Operator for column.", 400);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException ignored) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Everything is working as expected, except for 1 problem. How do I dynamically query the parent? Deployment class has a Parent object joined on Deployment.parentId column. I would like for 1 of 2 scenarios if possible.

1. criteria.getKey == parentId. Then I would like to just get the predicate for the join column (parentId).
2. criteria.getKey == Parent.. Then I would like to be able to get the predicate for the Parent..

One option I thought of is the following, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this. Maybe an annotation on the Deployment.Parent property?

```
try {
    Field field = QDeployment.class.getDeclaredField(criteria.getKey());
    if (field.getType == Parent.class) {
        Path<?> val = (Path<NumberPath>) QParent.parentId;
         }
        // rest of code above
}
```

The goal is that I need to be able to dynamically query Deployment entity, without knowing the column. I also need to include the Parent object in some queries.

Comment: I think the field type of parent will be QParent. One suggestion is to make the `getPredicate` function generic (by passing the qClass object as parameter), so that if the type of field is another qClass you can simply call the same function again (To allow nested querying).

Comment: That's an interesting idea. However, how would I go about fetching the QParent property? If say "Parent.parentId" was my criteria key, then " Field field = QDeployment.class.getDeclaredField(criteria.getKey());" would throw an exception

Comment: The `Class` object can be accessed by `getType()` function from your `Field` object. And you need to parameterise the `Class` object.